# Extracting features from bounding boxes of CornerNet

Tags: deep-learning, convolutional-neural-network, computer-vision, object-detection

I am using the [CornerNet model](https://github.com/princeton-vl/CornerNet). I want to extract features from specific bounding boxes that have been detected.

Unlike `Faster RCNN`,`CornerNet` does not use anchors proposals that allow extraction of features for each of the [bounding boxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33650653/extracting-features-from-all-bounding-boxes-of-fast-r-cnn). Rather, it just outputs `heatmaps` with corner points for each category. I am unsure how I can get features of a particular bbox from these `heatmaps`.

This is almost certainly not the way to go, but I'm thinking of training another feature extractor like the first half of an `Autoencoder`. I can crop the image according to the boxes detected by `CornerNet` and feed the cropped image to the feature extractor to get some representations for the required objects.

Could anyone suggest a more direct approach or point out something I missed?

PS - I have been shooed away from stackoverflow for asking the same question because some people felt it is not relevant there. If anything, please tell me what I can improve in the question before closing it altogether.